# Trying to scrape Reddit data and not finding the results

Tags: python, keyword, reddit

```
#Search for posts relating to keywords

keywords = []

search_term='handbags'
keyword='color'

ml_subreddit = reddit.subreddit('handbags')

if (len(sys.argv)>1):
    search_term=(sys.argv[1])

if (len(sys.argv)>2):
    keyword=(sys.argv[2])

print ("Subreddit: ",search_term)
print ("Keyword: ",keyword)

resp = ml_subreddit.search(keyword,limit=10)

for submission in resp:
    print ("=ID: ",submission.id)
    print ("  Title: ",submission.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    print ("  Score: ",submission.score)
    print ("  URL: ",submission.url.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
    print ("  Text: ",submission.selftext[:120].encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
```

it spit out

Subreddit:  -f
Keyword:  /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-b525623e-0886-4b49-a5ad-3bc17af8509a.json

Comment: Are you using pushshift or the Reddit API? Are you using a library? If so, which one?

Comment: Reddit API and using tweepy praw textblob
 pandas
matplotlib
 seaborn